# Validation for empty text box

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, multidatatrigger

I have three text boxes on my wpf application. When the user enters the value in these text boxes and clicks on `Add`, these are added to the list and displayed in data grid.

The text boxes are not bound to anything as such and I add these text box values to an observale collection bound to data grid. I want to prevent the user to enter empty values in text boxes. How is that done?

I saw some examples but those all had the text box boudn to values and then used `Binding.Validation`. How will this be done in my case when there's binding to text box?

I also have a button which has to be freezed when the empty values are being entered.  for that, I sed the following approach by making a class and binding the class in the following manner;

```
<Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox1, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox2, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=TextBoxAge, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false" />                                
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
```

**.cs class**

```
 public class TextBoxNotEmptyValidationRule : ValidationRule
    {
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            string str = value as string;
            if (str != null)
            {
                if (str.Length > 0)
                    return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
            }
            return new ValidationResult(false, Message);
        }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Why not bind your textboxes to values, as with the examples you've seen?  This will encourage you towards better-structured code, which will benfit you longer term.

Comment: @DanPuzey: Can you explain how that binding will occur and the values will be added to the observable collection? I kind of didn't get that concept ;-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right you're looking for something like this:

```
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox1}" Value="{x:Static s:String.Empty}" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox2}" Value="{x:Static s:String.Empty}" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=TextBoxAge}" Value="{x:Static s:String.Empty}" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

Add this namespace

```
xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

**Update**

Then this will work:

```
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <local:MyTextValidationConverter x:Key="MyTextValidationConverter" />
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyTextValidationConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="textBox1" />
                    <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="textBox2" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

And this Converter code

```
public class MyTextValidationConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string text1 = values[0] as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text1)) return false;

        string text2 = values[1] as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text2)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like filling one of the text box enable the button. I want to enforece the non-empty validation for two of these text boxes.

Comment: Specify what you want. Which two TextBoxes? And do you want the Button enabled if both non empty or only one?

Comment: `textBox1` and `textBox2` should not accept empty inputs. Both should be filled by the user before the button is enabled. The third text box can be empty though

Comment: That's a pity because there is no "Or"-MultiDataTrigger or any check for NotEmpty. I've edited my answer with a MultiBinding solution.

Comment: And this is supposed to be better than using code to perform these tasks?  WPF boggles my mind... You have replaced a single if statement with ~40 lines of nonsense.

Comment: @EdS. If he would follow MVVM it would be almost as easy.

Comment: @LPL: ...I just enjoy ranting about WPF, don't take me too seriously :D.  I can't stand the fact that they made simple tasks hard in an effort to make previously difficult tasks easier.

Comment: @LPL: Can you mention how it would be easy(ier) with MVVM becuase I am following the pattern right now

Comment: @LPL: And instead of Oe MultiData Trigger, is there an and multidata trigger o so I can make all of the text boxes mandatory

Comment: MultiDataTrigger is "And" by default. All conditions have to be true to trigger. In MVVM you would bind all TextBox.Text and Button.IsEnabled properties to corresponding properties in a ViewModel which you set as DataContext of your View. Then in ViewModel you can access all needed strings to compute if button should be enabled `get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(text1) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(text2); }`. Or you use Commands ...